# Update table with row_numbers without unique ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, row-number

I have a travel time table where each day is segmented by 288 5 minute epochs. I want to create a count of these epochs from 0-287 for each day. So the count resets for each day so each day has a 0-287 count. I got this far but I'm getting a incorrect syntax error.

```
update [dbo].[table]
   set count = count2 
  from (
    select 
       row_number() over (partition by date order by epoch) as count2 
    from [dbo].[table]
  )
```

Comment: please share an example of your data and required result

Comment: 113+04318 2017-02-01 1
113+04318 2017-02-01 2
113+04318 2017-02-01 3
113+04318 2017-02-01 4
113+04318 2017-02-01 5

I don't know how to format comments here.

Comment: Don't post code or sample data in the comments...it has not ability to format correctly. More importantly you need to provide some actual details here. Namely the table structure, sample data and desired output for your sample. As posted this is nearly impossible to answer. With details this is likely quite simple. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

For correcting syntax error in your code, try this:

```
Update  [dbo].[table]  set count = t.count2 -1
from (select datecol, epoch, row_number() over (partition by datecol 
order by epoch) as count2 from  [dbo].[table] ) t
inner join [dbo].[table] tt on t.datecol = tt.datecol and t.epoch = tt.epoch
```

Comment: That did not work, as the count isn't resetting back to zero for each epoch on each day.

Comment: That's strange... this code was tested! But may be because I had assumed data in a different way...! Glad that you have got it working anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell sql server what rows you want to update. SQL server does not know how you want to join these tables.

First I would make sure the count looks ok on it's own.

```
select 
    date,
    epoch,
    row_number() over (partition by date order by epoch) as count2 
from [dbo].[table]
```

**edit**

I hadn't test my answer, sorry about that.
This should work:

```
update dbo.table
    set count = c2.rnc
from dbo.table
join (
    select
        epoch,
        date,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by date order by epoch) as rnc
    from dbo.table
) as c2
    on c2.epoch = table.epoch
    and c2.date = table.date
```

Comment: Yes, the select statement works but the update statement does not. I am trying to fix the latter.

Comment: @BenZeddicus I hadn't check my work! take a look now and see if this fits your needs.

Comment: That still does not work. Looks like the join on the days is messing up with the count order. There are 600 TMCs, of which are made up of 11 months of days, of which are made up of 5 minute epochs. So joining on days means that the same day is repeated 600 times in the count sequence since one day per one TMC.

Comment: Ok, so what really needs to happen is to identify what makes each row unique. So if thats `months, days, epoch` or `table_id` or whatever, that is what needs to be in the subquery and the join. 

Without a full table definition, it's hard to say exactly what you should be looking at. If you would like to provide the table schema, that might help.

Comment: All right got it to work. Your code required the partition on both tmc and date. I did not know that was possible until I took a wild shot at it.